# Wordpress Sidebar Widget CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

Using Firebug, I finally (this has been an ongoing struggle) found the CSS that I need to edit to fix my sidebar spacing program. It's below:

```
#sidebar .widget {
margin-bottom: 45px;
position: relative;
}
```

What I want to do is edit the margin-bottom to be 5px instead of 45. However, I cannot seem to find this specific CSS anywhere. When I find it through Firebug, it's in a file called all.css, but I can only edit the style.css file through Wordpress.

I've tried changing it in the custom CSS, but that doesn't fix anything. Can someone please help me? I know nothing about CSS, and I was so excited to finally figure out what I need to change, and now I can't change it!

Comment: Try #sidebar .widget { margin-bottom: 5px !important; }

Comment: @ Jay Bhatt, That's not necessary if the OP has WP installed on their own server. But nevertheless is a quick solution to a minor problem. JavaScript could be used to override this; if all else fails.

Comment: Firebug should give you the full path to the all.css From the wordpress editor you should be able to edit that file whether its a theme file or if its a plugin file.

Comment: @JayBhatt I tried that already. No change.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the `<head>` section, if the `style.css` is loaded **after** the `all.css`. If not, you must provide a CSS rule that will be more precise than the one from `all.css`, e.g.

```css
#sidebar div.widget {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

(if the `.widget` is a `div`, of course)

Comment: It would be good practice to provide a more specific rule anyway, to conform to an architecturally solid style-sheet. Good answer though. +1

Comment: @JackWilliams I completely agree with you. I didn't mention that because I don't know the DOM of this particular website but I could have mention it anyway. Well, that's what the comments are for, I guess.

Comment: @matewka Sorry, I'm very new at CSS. Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Actually I can't until you show how the HTML look like. I mean, that part with `#sidebar` and its content.